# How should I connect multiple clauses?

Tags: clauses

How should I connect multiple clauses(because, when, while, as, etc)?

Should I use the same words or **that**?

Example 01

> > That information is wrong, because it is unpredictable how the building or furniture might collapse during an earthquake, and **because** it is more likely to injure ourselves that way.

Example 02

> > That information is wrong, because it is unpredictable how the building or furniture might collapse during an earthquake, and **that** it is more likely to injure ourselves that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> That information is wrong, because it is unpredictable how the building or furniture might collapse during an earthquake, and because it is more likely to injure ourselves that way.

Isn't entirely correct. Here are some better ways to say this.

> That information is wrong, because it is unpredictable how the building or furniture may collapse during an earthquake, meaning increased risk of injury.
>
> That information is wrong due to the unpredictability of the furniture or the building collapsing during an earthquake, which increases the chance of personal injury.
>
> The information presented is incorrect because it is unpredictable how the furniture or building may collapse in the event of an earthquake, which could lead to personal injury.
>
> The information is wrong because it is not possible to predict how the furniture or building would collapse in the event of an earthquake, meaning the chances of injury are higher.

Those are a few ways to phrase this, though I'm sure there are many more. You can't say **it is more likely to injure ourselves that way**.  You could say **it is more likely to injure us.** Or something similar.

Comment: Thank you for providing other sentences!!! So, Example 01 is correct?

Comment: My apologies, my first quote was just repeating what you said, so you could compare it to other sentences. Let me fix to clarify.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, I mean that how I connect my clauses is correct?? Should I use the same words(because, that, when, etc)?

Comment: Yes your first example's clauses are connected fine. The second one doesn't make too much sense and would have to be reworded. Hope that helps.